# How to call a method via a variable in threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, class, variables, python-multithreading

I'm using the threading class in Python... The variable device is a list of objects. Am I somehow able to convert a 'string' of a variable to translate into a method such that the threading class understands it?

```
def thread():
    var_string = 'some_func'
    index = 0
    some_thread = threading.Thread(target=device[index].<var_string> , args=())
```

So essentially, I would like to call `device[index].somefunc()`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it to work as intended...

I used the function [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) like so:

```
var_string = 'some_func'
some_thread = threading.Thread(target=getattr(ntw_device[index], var_string), args=())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
target=getattr(device[index], var_string)
```